# Create unique URL for Google Form when redirected from a survey platform

Tags: google-forms

I am trying to host a survey. In thank you page I require interested participants to click on a link that redirects them to a Google Form where they have to provide their contact information. However, I want the URL generated on clicking the link on survey thank you page to be unique. This would ensure that participants who have not taken the survey cannot access the Google Form. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Google Forms doesn't include that feature. The closed that can be don is that you use prefilled URL where you survey adds a unique code but later you should have to check that the unique code was not used twice and that only valid unique codes were used.

Comment: By the way, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].